# How to figure out why `bash simple_script.sh` works but `bash < simple_script.sh` doesn't?

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I have a very simple script, `simple_script.sh`, consisting the following three lines

```
bpeek 123450
bpeek 123451
bpeek 123452
```

If I run

```
$ bash simple_script.sh
```

all three `bpeek` commands in `simple_script.sh` get executed.

But if I run

```
$ bash < simple_script.sh
```

...only the first of the `bpeek` commands get executed<sup>1</sup>, *AND* the script's run terminates successfully (i.e. with `$?` equal to 0).

In contrast, if I were to replace `bpeek` with `/bin/echo` (for example), both ways of running `simple_script.sh` would result in the execution of all three commands.

I'm quick to add that I have never before observed such difference (between these two ways of running a bash script); the difference I described above has something to do, quite specifically, with the `bpeek` command (which is part of [IBM's LSF suite](https://www.ibm.com/products/hpc-workload-management)).  (To be clear, the "bare" command `bpeek` resolves to a file, not a function or an alias, and `file` reports said file to be an "ELF 64-bit LSB executable.")

I am baffled by this difference, and would like to figure out ***why*** it happens.

My question is: what can I do to establish an explanation for this difference?

---

Of course, there is no reason for me to invoke `simple_script.sh` like this:

```
$ bash < simple_script.sh
```

This is something I'm doing here only to simplify this question.  In practice, however, I would like to be able to run commands of the form

```
<PIPELINE> | bash
```

...where `<PIPELINE>` writes to `stdout` several commands of the form `bpeek <JOBID>` (one command per line), and I would like all these commands to get executed, not just the first one.

My hope is that by understanding better what is going on, I will be able to modify `<PIPELINE>` in a way that ensures all the commands get executed.

Besides, I just want to understand what on earth is going on.  (After all, I can always accept my ignorance, and just resort to `bash <( <PIPELINE> )`.)

FWIW: The problem is not specific to `bash`.  Exactly the same thing happens if I replace `bash` with `zsh` in the above.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> More precisely, only the output of the first `bpeek` command shows up on my terminal.</sup>

Comment: Does `bpeek` itself read from the standard input stream?

Comment: Try to run bash with the `-s` flag.

Comment: @steeldriver: not that I'm aware of; the manual page for `bpeek` does not mention `stdin` at all.

Comment: @aviro: `bash -s < simple_script.sh` behaves just like `bash < simple_script.sh`.  On the other hand, `bash -s simple_script.sh` does not run `simple_script.sh` at all; it just starts an interactive subshell.

Comment: Having read a bit about what `bpeek` does (attach to the stdout of a running process, and `cat` it) I suspect it is playing with file descriptors under the hood. Perhaps it closes (rather than reading from) its stdin? I can simulate the same behavior replacing the bpeek commands with  `echo 123450; exec 0<&-` and `echo 123451; exec 0<&-` etc.